# VueJS - Prevent Default on link click but also capture object

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am learning Vue.JS and have run into a bit of a problem. I want the user to be able to click on an `<a href="#"></a>` tag, `e.preventDefault()`, and also grab the object associated with the link. Here is my code (note that I have `@` preceding the `{{` because I am using Blade):

```
<a href="#"
   class="list-group-item"
   v-repeat="responder: responders"
   v-on="click: showResponder(responder)">
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-left">
            <img src="" v-attr="src: responder.avatar" alt="" class="media-object"/>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">@{{ responder.first_name }} @{{ responder.last_name }}</h4>
            <p>
                <strong><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Phone:</strong> @{{ responder.phone }}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

And the Javascript:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#responderContainer",
    data: {
        activeResponder: null,
        responders: []
    },
    methods: {
        showResponder: function(responder)
        {
            // Here is where I wish to prevent the 
            // link from actually firing its default action
            responder.preventDefault();
            this.activeResponder = responder;
        }
    }
});
```

This works as far as grabbing the `responder` object but fires the link - I need to be able to both `e.preventDefault()` AND get the object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [documentation](http://vuejs.org/guide/events.html) shows you can pass $event to get the event object

> http://vuejs.org/guide/events.html
>
> ```
> <button v-on="click: submit('hello!', $event)">Submit</button>
>
> /* ... */
> {
>   methods: {
>     submit: function (msg, e) {
>       e.stopPropagation()
>     }
>   }
> }
> /* ... */
> ```

So you want the v-on attribute to be

```
v-on="click: showResponder(responder,$event)"
```

and the function definition to be

```
showResponder: function(responder,e)
```

Answer (score 62):

Alternatively, in Vue 1.x, you could also use the [event modifier](https://vuejs.org/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) `.prevent`:

HTML:

```
<a v-on:click.prevent="showResponder(responder)">...</a>
```

You could stop propagation as well:

```
<a v-on:click.prevent.stop="showResponder(responder)">...</a>
```

JS:

```
...
            showResponder: function(responder)
            {
                // No need to prevent any more
                this.activeResponder = responder;
            }
...
```

Comment: It should actually be `v-on:click.prevent`

Comment: How do you prevent event propagation when there is no method to call, e.g. a simple `<a href="mailto:someone@example.org">` link?

Comment: To @MladenDanic's point, `prevent` will prevent default behavior, and `prevent.stop` will *also* stop propagation. For example: If you are triggering a custom method from an anchor click in a dropdown navigation, `prevent.stop` will also prevent the 'click' event, and leave the dropdown open. `prevent` will halt the anchor link, but allow the event to bubble for the 'click' behavior

Comment: @AdamReis In my case I wanted to prevent click on the `tr` from a `table` when I clicking in an ' href` without a method. I used `.self` in the ' td` and moved the method from the `tr'  to each `td`. Check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68838076/how-to-ignore-that-clicking-on-a-td-tag-does-not-automatically-redirect-me-to-an/74465289#74465289

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
@click.stop
```

on a parent element to stop event bubbling if you want to use href and not the custom click events.

```
<div @click.stop>
  <a href="//google.ca">Google</a>
</div>
```