# How to ignore that clicking on a TD tag does not automatically redirect me to another view? Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have a table where in each TR when I click it redirects me to another view with the detail, the idea is that I have never worked with Vue and I can't think how to disable the event when I click on the first TD tag of the table.

Before in Jquery I did it this way:

```
//Add onclick to TR
  $('table tr').click(function(e) {
    // Avoid redirecting if it's a delete button
    if(!$(e.currentTarget).hasClass('delete')) {
      // Not a button, redirect by taking the attribute from data-route
      window.location.href = $(e.currentTarget).data('route');
    }
  });
```

But with Vue I don't know how to do it in the onclick event.

This is my table and the method

```
<table
  id="accounts-table"
  class="
    table table-listbox
    table-bordered_
    table-responsive-md
    table-striped_
    text-center_
  "
>
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-if="tableData.length === 0">
      <td colspan="4" class="text-center">
        No hay oportunidades para mostrar.
      </td>
    </tr>

    <template v-if="loading === true">
        <tr colspan="9" class="text-center">
          <b-spinner variant="primary" label="Spinning"></b-spinner>
          <b-spinner variant="primary" type="grow" label="Spinning"></b-spinner>
        </tr>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <tr
      v-for="(data, k) in tableData"
      :key="k"
      @click="viewOpportunity(k, data)"
    >
      <slot :row="data">
        <td v-if="permissions.includes('view all opportunities')" width="10">
          <div class="iq-email-sender-info">
            <div class="iq-checkbox-mail">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="mailk">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="mailk"></label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td width="20">
          <vue-avatar
            :username="data.sales_man"
            :title="data.sales_man"
            :size="32"
            v-if="data.sales_man != ''"
          ></vue-avatar>
        </td>
        <td width="5">
          <template v-if="data.has_file != false">
            <i
              class="ri-attachment-line"
              style="font-size: 20px; color: #007bff"
            ></i>
          </template>
        </td>
        <td width="120" nowrap>
          <template>
            <p class="mb-0">{{ data.created_at }}</p>
            <small class="text-info mt-5">
              Fecha creación
            </small>
          </template>
        </td>
      </slot>
      </tr>
    </template>

  </tbody>
</table>

viewOpportunity(data) {
  window.location.href = "/opportunity/" + data.id;
},
```

For example in the first TD of the table I would like that it does not redirect me to the page but from the 2nd TD it redirects me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On first td element use this even modifier -  @click.stop

[Prevent on click on parent when clicking button inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45700632/prevent-on-click-on-parent-when-clicking-button-inside-div)

This kind of issue ever answered .. please have a look on this

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs an href inside a table that has a that has a `@click` method in the row, but you wat to the link does not fire the click event in the row and also to prevent event propagation when there is no method to call, e.g. a simple `<a href="mailto:someone@example.org">` link, try to use this trick with **`@click.self`**:

**BEFORE**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>COLUMN A</th>
      <th>COLUMN B</th>
   </tr>
   <tr @click="myMethodFromRow">
      <td>Some Value</td>
      <td>
         <a target="_blank" :href="mailto:someone@example.org"> My link </a>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**AFTER**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>COLUMN A</th>
      <th>COLUMN B</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td @click="myMethodFromRow">Some Value</td>
      <td @click.self="myMethodFromRow">
         <a target="_blank" :href="mailto:someone@example.org"> My link </a>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

In this case I wanted to execute `myMethodFromRow` clicking inside each `td`, but not clicking the `link`. So I changed the `myMethodFromRow` method from the `tr` and put it into each `td`. But the most important trik was to use **`@click.self`** for the `td` with the href link.

`.self` only trigger handler if event.target is the element itself, i.e. not from a child element.

**DOCUMENTATION**: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers